# Rewrite rule to HTTPS and WWW except when on localhost

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

Removed previous post due to my carelessness and posted the live domain.

I've having trouble building a functioning Web.config rule that will direct traffic from `http:// to https://www` and `http://www to https://www` and `https:// to https://www` EXCEPT when on `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` while I'm doing some development.

Web.config

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="Redirect non-www OR non-https to https://www">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
```

Updated and working rule, maybe there is something wrong that someone could point out?

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="Enforce HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern"
              pattern="^localhost(:\d+)?$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"
            appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect example.com to www.example.com"
           enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^www]" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern"
              pattern="^localhost(:\d+)?$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}"
           appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Create a rule above to break early https://blog.lextudio.com/iis-url-rewrite-tip-break-free-adccdb4b9f2f

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware the rules were able to be stacked and ordered. Thank you, I'll look into that and post an update if I can resolve the issue.

Comment: You can read FRT to learn what might be wrong, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: If you add the stop stopProcessing to true, it will not execute another url rewrite rule.